# Finding Closed Form Formula of a Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a block of code that prints a certain statement and I need to find a closed form formula to calculate the number of statements printed. So far, I have the following sum, but don't know how to find a formula for it:

$$(n-3)+2(n-4)+3(n-5)+4(n-6)+\cdots+(n-2)(n-n)$$

The last term implies that a single statement is printed because I have a loop that goes from some integer $i$ to $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You want to compute
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} i(n-2-i)=(n-2)\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} i- \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}i^2$$ It looks simple.